# #pragma target 3.0 or 3.5? What is gained. What is lost for compatibility with older systems

Tags: unity, shaders

I've just designed an image-based layering system shader. Multiple textures with Alphas overlay to create a fully dressed character, using 1 material.

## pragma target 3.0 is where I had started (suggested default in UnityProjects).

After creating so many transparent-overlay layers in my code, I got this:

Shader error in 'Custom/Test': Too many texture interpolators would be used for ForwardBase pass (12 out of max 10)

The fix seems to be to upgrade to **#pragma target 3.5**

My game is going to be a Steam-distributed game, PC only.

What do I lose by using #pragma target 3.5? Will only super-dvanced PCs be compatible? Or should a fairly good/average PC be able to run this?

I don't know the intricacies of this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be explained in the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-ShaderCompileTargets.html):

> - #pragma target 3.5 (or es3.0) OpenGL ES 3.0 capabilities (DX10 SM4.0 on D3D platforms, just without geometry shaders).
> - Not supported on DX11 9.x (WinPhone), OpenGL ES 2.0.
> - Supported on DX11+, OpenGL 3.2+,
>   OpenGL ES 3+, Metal, Vulkan, PS4/XB1 consoles.
> - Native integer
>   operations in shaders, texture arrays and so on.

Comparing this to the numbers from the [Steam hardware survey for May
2020](https://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey/videocard/):

> OVERALL DISTRIBUTION OF CARDS...MAY
>
> - DirectX 12 `92.02%`
> - DirectX 11 `3.99%`
> - DirectX 10 `2.23%`
> - DirectX 9 Shader Model 2b and 3.0 `0.04%`
> - DirectX 9 Shader Model 2.0 `0.00%`
> - DirectX 8 GPUs and below `1.72%`

So it looks like you'd exclude less than 2% of the Steam audience by using `#pragma target 3.5`.

Comment: Thats a great answer. I didn't know about the steam data you've dug up, so thank you very much.

Comment: Hahaha, if this is a free-to-play game, maybe I'd exclude more since my audience might be people who can't afford better hardware. :D So that 2% might be the audience.

Comment: That's a question you'll answer only through market research, not via StackExchange 